# Django- How to replace list of items of a related set

Tags: python, django

I have table Group and UserConfig

- A group has many users, each user in a group has a config item
- UserConfig: unique (group_id, user_id)

Example:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

class UserConfig(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_configs')
    user_id = models.IntegerField()
    config = models.JSONField()
```

I want to replace all UserConfig instances of a group (update existing rows, add new rows and remove which rows are not in the new list)

```
# list_replace_configs: List[UserConfig]
group.user_configs.set(list_replace_configs, bulk=False, clear=False)
```

This method not working because it uses method `remove()`

- remove(*objs, bulk=True): only exists if ForeignKey field has null=True
- if ForeignKey field has null=True: it does not removed UserConfig object, but just set user_config.group = None

I don't understand why django designs this method.
**How to replace all UserConfig instances of a group ?**

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using `constraints` in class `Meta`:
(In Django `id` in generate auto and you don't need to add it as a field)

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

class UserConfig(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_configs')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_configs')
    
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['user', 'group',],
                                    name='unique_user_config')
        ]
```

Comment: I mange users in User service, so I have to use user_id = models.IntegerField(). And each row (user_id, group_id) needs field config = models.JSONField(). The above tables are only an example.